# Opening OptionsMenu on the touch of a tab of the TabActivity

Tags: android, menu, android-tabhost, tabactivity, android-optionsmenu

I have a tabActivity where I am adding tabs on runtime. So I think this is the usual code to do that:

```
_tabSpec = TabHost.newTabSpec("More");
_tabSpec.setIndicator("", Resources.GetDrawable(Resources.Drawable.myIcon).SetContent(intent);
TabHost.AddTab(_tabSpec);
```

Now the thing is, I have defined an options menu and I want to pop that up when the user clicks on the 'More' tab. I don't know how to do that. I tried not setting a content on that tab and simply use the `OpenOptionsMenu()` to pop it, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any clue how to achieve that?
P.S.: This is a C# code written in Xamarin. It might not look like the native java-android code, but its almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String lastTab = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Tab 1");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, OneActivity.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Tab 2");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("more");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("More");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, OneActivity.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("more")){
                    openOptionsMenu();
                    tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(lastTab);
                }
                else lastTab = tabId;

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: So you mean I should just add a tab and set any intent on that and then add this onTabChangedListener?

Comment: Its not working. I set a blank activity and that activity is displayed when the user clicks the last tab... the menu pops fine, which isn't an issue anymore. Howeever, I don't want to show the user that blank activity. I just want it like a button. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(lastTab) should change your tab on last active tab if user checks "more". Can you check via debugger how works this function?

Comment: Dimmerg, the onTabChanged will trigger the code on changing the tab everytime. Your solution is invalid. I didn't try the serCurrentTabByTag though.

Comment: I've updated my code. I created test project and it works good - it opens options menu when I tap on "More" tab and moves user on last tab - as user I don't see tab changing.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here's an answer to what I was trying to do.

Motive: Add a 'More' tab to the existing TabActivity. When user clicks it, open some kind of a PopUpWindow or ContextMenu, etc.

Steps to do that:

1) Create a tabSpec and add that tab to the TabHost as shown in the question.
2) Now you need to take in this last added tab as a View type variable. Do this by..

```
View v = TabWidget.GetChildAt(index)
```

Remember index of tabs starts from 0
3) Now on the onCreate() method of your main activity (one that holds the TabActivity) add an `onTouchListener()` (I use C#, so I added `v.Click+=myFunction()`) and write your code of the PopupWindow or ContextMenu or whatever you want to do there.